# Incompatible type error Geocoder Google API

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I am trying to use the geocoder API by google in Android.

Here's  the code :

```
 private void getLatLong(String inputaddress) throws IOException {
        Geocoder mygeocoder = new Geocoder(this.getContext());
        List<Address> gclist = mygeocoder.getFromLocationName(inputaddress,1);
    }
```

However, I get an error:

```
Error: incompatible types: List<android.location.Address> cannot be converted to List<com.google.android.gms.identity.intents.Address>
```

While declaring the List, I am making sure that it is importing from the `com.google.android.gms.identity.intents.Address` , still I am getting this error. 
Any idea where am I going wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Your List declaration is an android.location.Address type. Try changing this to com.google.android.gms.identity.intents.Address

Answer (score 3):

This did the work

```
List<android.location.Address> gclist ;
        gclist  = mygeocoder.getFromLocationName(inputaddress,1);
```